# How to connect Fabric.js objects programmatically with a connector

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs, connector

I want to connect two fabric.js objects with connectors. How can i achieve this? For example i have two fabric objects like this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

$("#rect").on("click", function (e) {
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 40,
        top: 40,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: "cornflowerblue",
        stroke: "cornflowerblue",

    });
    canvas.add(rect);
});

$("#rect").on("click", function (e) {
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 40,
        top: 40,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: "cornflowerblue",
        stroke: "cornflowerblue",

    });
    canvas.add(rect);
});
```

I have a button named " Connector " 
when clicking the button it should allow me to click on any object to start making a line from the selected object to another object.

I'm not using angular or react. I'm doing this on jQuery. 
I have googled but fed up. Here im seeking for a step by step guide.

Comment: Duplicate. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148390/how-to-draw-connector-lines-between-shapes-by-dragging-mouse-in-fabricjs

Comment: See also: https://robferguson.org/blog/2016/01/21/adding-support-for-ports-and-connectors-to-fabric-js/

Comment: @NoGrabbing i think this link provides the solution in angular. but im not coding on angular. i want jQuery solution. can you please guide? or give me a link

Comment: @NoGrabbing Please help.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const rectz = rect.getPointByOrigin('center')
  const recty = rect1.getPointByOrigin('center')
  const connector = new fabric.Line(
    [rectz.x, rectz.y, recty.x, recty.y],
    {
      stroke: '#8470ff',
      strokeWidth: 3,
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      lockRotation: false,
      hasControls: false,
      hasBorders: false,
      lockMovementX: true,
      lockMovementY: true
    }
  )



  rect.on('moving', function() {
  const connectPoint = this.getPointByOrigin('center')
     console.log(connectPoint,"centerpoint");
    connector.set({
      x1: connectPoint.x,
      y1: connectPoint.y
    })
  })

  rect1.on('moving', function() {
    const connectPoint1 = this.getPointByOrigin('center')
    connector.set({
      x2: connectPoint1.x,
      y2: connectPoint1.y
    })
  })

  canvas.add(connector,rect, rect1);
```

1.while defining second give the rect as rect1. 
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/chinmaykademane/2L9qhrzw/9/)